# Emulating RGBA for IE8

Tags: css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8

I would like to emulate:
background: `rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);` and background: `rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.45);` for IE8
I managed to get it working with this :

```
-ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#4C000000, endColorstr=#4C000000)";
```

Which can be used for  `rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);`

How can I have the right Colorstr for 0.25 and 0.45 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

see here [calculate ARGB for RGBA](http://web.archive.org/web/20131207234608/http://kilianvalkhof.com/2010/css-xhtml/how-to-use-rgba-in-ie/)

```css
body{
    background: #FFF8DC;
}

div{
    width: 200px;
    height: 100px;
    margin: 10px auto;
    
}
.div1{
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#3F000000, endColorstr=#3F000000)";
}
.div2{
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.45);
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#72000000, endColorstr=#72000000)";
}
```

```html
<div class="div1"></div>
<div class="div2"></div>
```